# Rebooting Old Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, sql-server

I have a question that may be really easy to answer.

Our company got a new server a while ago. This server acts as our DNS, SQL, Web, NAS, and Active Directory. We are moving to a new office and I thought since a bunch of things are changing we may as well take the old server and make it our SQL/Web server so it is separate from everything else on the new server.

I have the old server booted up (not plugged into the network), and I am wondering if there would be any implications of me connecting this to the network. Would the old and new server so called 'fight' for priority on the network? The old server has all of the user accounts, shares, and everything else?

The new server is running Windows Server 2012, and the old one is running Windows Server 2003.

Additionally, is there any other heads up you can recommend for doing this swap?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you disabled all network services (DNS, AD, possibly others, ...) on the old server, leaving only SQL Server and a web server? For example two AD servers might not play terribly well if they don't know about each other.

Comment: Sorry, I am not too familiar with how to do this. So no, I have not. How would I go about disabling all of the features? Or would a fresh install of Windows Server be easier?

Comment: Just do a fresh install, you'll save yourself lots of grief.

Comment: I'm reformatting as we speak!

Comment: @ChaseErnst In that case, I suggest that you delete your question, so people don't spend time answering something that won't help you and might not help others very much.

Comment: I cannot, because there is an answer attached.

Answer (score -1):

How are IP addresses assigned at your company? If you're using DHCP then it's not an issue. If you're not - then ensure the IP address of the machine if different to that of the current one as to avoid IP Address conflicts.

Outside of that, presuming it's a fresh windows install - shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: This answer does not have a lot of detail and will be down-voted very quickly. Provide more details in your answer or move this to the comment section.

Comment: The IP addresses are different. I do that know. But there is not a fresh install of Windows Server on the old server. I guess that would make sense to do that.

Comment: Zain - the answer perfectly answers the OP's question. He is simply asking about conflicts. There isn't much more to say outside of checking that the same static IP isn't assigned.

Chase - I would highly recommend a fresh install of windows. There are too many things that can go wrong if you use the the existing installation.

Comment: Hmm, alright. Since I am not too familiar with installing a brand new install of Window Server, would I just need to install SQL Server and IIS Server and be good to go?

Comment: You'd need to configure each one of those applications - but in essence, yes!

As for the people like zain.ali downvoting my answer - they need to learn to actually create a solution for the OP in accordance with their technical ability, instead of behaving like evangelists in all cases.

Comment: Evangelists? In no way am I trying to convert you to Christianity :)  Anyway, I was really trying to help you rather than criticize your answer, sorry if you feel offended - but I did warn you that your answer will get down-voted due to it's lack of detail. :( My comment was supposed to encourage you to improve your answer ;D  @user1203297

Comment: Read that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_evangelist
My answer has had 2 downvotes, 1 of which has been from yourself. You can quite clearly see the technical ability of the OP. A simple solution for a one off situation is what he was looking for. There would be little point me explaining to him how IP addresses are assigned by a DHCP server and what happens when an IP address conflict occurs.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: If you have a question to ask the OP you should ask that as a comment on their question. When they reply **then** you write an answer.

Comment: R Drast - if you'd managed to comprehend my answer you'd quite clearly see how I suggested OP reinstalls the OS, as to avoid those issues, but congrats on spreading that wisdom.